# Не обновляются данные на других ПК при изменение записи

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

При  добавлении записи в БД, данные в DataGrid добавляются на всех ПК, но при изменение данные не обновляются.

1. Добавление элемента

   ```
   JournalDBEntities db = new JournalDBEntities();

   private void btnAddOrder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Data d = new Data();
       string timeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yy hh:mm");
       d.applicationDateAndTime = timeNow + "," + tbCar.Text;
       d.dateAndTimeOfCarProvision = dtpick.Text + " " + tbHours.Text + ":" + tbMinuts.Text;
       d.purposesOfUsingAuto = cbPurposesOfUsingAuto.Text;
       d.cargo = tbCargo.Text;
       d.route = tbRoute.Text;

       d.id_employe = Properties.Settings.Default.idUser;

       if(tbCar.Text == "Грузовая")
           d.nameDocument = tbNameDocument.Text;
       else
           d.nameDocument = "Нет";

       d.applicationStatus = "Не выполненно";
       db.Data.Add(d);
       db.SaveChanges();
       this.Close();
   }
   ```
2. Обновление datagrid

   ```
   public async void UpdataTable(){
       while (true){    

               g1.ItemsSource = db.Data.ToList().AsEnumerable().Reverse().Take(10);

               await Task.Delay(15000);       
       }
   }
   ```

   При загрузке формы вызван этот метод

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       UpdataTable();
   }
   ```
3. Кнопка для изменений

   ```
   private void editButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       int cell = Convert.ToInt32(epID.Text);
       var cellEdit = db.Data.Where(w => w.id == cell).FirstOrDefault();
       cellEdit.applicationDateAndTime = epApplicationDateAndTime.Text;
       cellEdit.dateAndTimeOfCarProvision = epDateAndTimeOfCarProvision.Text;
       cellEdit.purposesOfUsingAuto = epPurposesOfUsingAuto.Text;
       cellEdit.route = epRoute.Text;
       cellEdit.nameDocument = epNameDocument.Text;
       cellEdit.id_employe = db.Employees.Where(x =>x.fullName == epLastName.Text).First().id;
       cellEdit.cargo = epCargo.Text;
       cellEdit.id_driver = epDriver.SelectedValue != null ? int.Parse(epDriver.SelectedValue.ToString()) : (int?)null ;
       cellEdit.applicationStatus = epApplicationStatus.Text;
       db.SaveChanges();
       g1.ItemsSource = db.Data.ToList().AsEnumerable().Reverse();
   }
   ```

P.S. Изменения производятся только на применявшим эти изменение ПК, а на других компьютерах изменения не производятся пока не перезагрузишь программу.

git: [Ссылка](https://github.com/olegarxs/Belhudojpromblslbl)

Comment: Как вы представляете себе - каким образом другие компьютеры узнают, что в БД что то поменялось?

Comment: `db.Data.ToList()` это вызов контекста данных? Он у вас один на всё приложение что ли?

Comment: я бы рекомендовал вам создавать контекст данных каждый раз, когда вам надо обратиться за данными, а не держать один контекст все время.

Comment: Ппц... Сперва загружаете _всю_ таблицу в память (`ToList`), потом берёте от неё небольшой кусочек: `Take(10)`, остальное выбрасывается. Поставьте `Take` в начало, тогда из БД будет загружаться только 10 строк.

Comment: надо что бы было автообновление данных и за совет спасибо) У меня несколько таблиц, но db.Data основная

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю `JournalDBEntities` является `DbContext`, если это так, то обновление данных не происходит из-за того, что при первом вызове `ToList()` все записи закешировались. Чтобы данные всегда были актуальны лучше всего создавать новый контекст при каждом обновлении данных, но можно также отрубить кеширование.

Код, который должен исправить обновление данных:

```
public async void UpdataTable(){
    while (true)
    {    
        using(var dbContext = new JournalDBEntities())
        {
            g1.ItemsSource = dbContext.Data.OrderBy(_ => _.Id).Reverse().Take(10).ToList();
        }
        await Task.Delay(15000);       
    }
}
```